Emacs window starts below all other open windows
On MacOS, when I start emacs, the window appears below all the other open windows on my screen, eg terminal, notes, etc.  I want it to open on top of all the other windows, not below them.

Do you see this when starting Emacs with emacs -Q (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

That sounds like a desktop environment problem, not an Emacs problem.

Thank both!
Interesting, I didn't know about -Q.  Still the same problem.  I could swear there's a setting in the init file that says to start it on top instead of at the bottom, but I'll look into this as a more general desktop env setting.

I've noticed this behavior "recently" myself; as in the past several months. Unsure if it's an Emacs or macOS issue. Doesn't bother me, and haven't cared enough to track it down. The machine I'm not right now (Ventura + Emacs 29.3) isn't exhibiting this behavior though.

So, on Sonoma (14.4.1) + Emacs 29.3, when starting Emacs from the Dock everything works as expected. If I start Emacs from the terminal (iTerm2) via emacs &! Emacs will start under the iTerm2 window (this may be an iTerm2 setting) and Emacs is last in the task list (⌘-TAB).

might be a bug related to https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=37529 or https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=47731

Son of a gun, @nega, when I start emacs from the dock, I don't have the problem.  It's only when I start it from iterm2.  I'll have to see if I can learn how to fix that.
